# php & mysql form data not been inserted in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to insert my form data into mysql, but when I enter the details and submit it, I am not able to get the data in database. May I know where am I wrong?

```js
<?php
// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 echo "jgj"
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sudhar";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else
{
 echo "connected"
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$Firstname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Firstname']);
$Lastname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Lastname']);
$Username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Username']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
$Password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Password']);

$sql="insert into useraccount(Firstname,Lastname,Username,email,Password)values('$Firstname','$Lastname','$Username','$Password','$email')";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)
echo "data inserted"
or die(mysql_error());
}
   ?>
```

```css
html,body
{
margin:0px; 
height:100%;
}
 .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 60%;
      margin: auto;
  }
 .content
 {
width:100%;
height:400px;
 }

 .signup
 {
height:500px;

 }
  .footer
  {
    position:relative;
   background-color:black;
  }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <title>ASK</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boot.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>school name</h1>                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="../project/photo/l.png"  height="150px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#mynavbar">schoolName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" target=_self>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="infra.html" target=_self>Infrastructure</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">Administration<span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="stlogin.html">staff login</a></li>
            <li><a href="stdetails.html">staff details</a></li>
            <li><a href="class.html">class handling</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="signup.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<div class="signup">
 <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="user.php">
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Firstname">Firstname:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Firstname" class="form-control" id="fnmae" placeholder="Enter Firstname">
    </div></div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Lastname">Lastname:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Lastname" class="form-control" id="lnmae" placeholder="Enter Lastname">
    </div></div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Username" class="form-control" id="unmae" placeholder="Enter Username">
    </div></div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div></div>        
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="Password" name="Password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div></div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button><br>
    
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer nav">
  <p> Copyrights@ &copy; WWW.schools.com</p>
  </div>   
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: so should i remove mysqli and replace with mysql

Comment: no error and data not been inserted@ rahul patel

Comment: MySQL is the database. `mysqli` is the PHP interface you're using to access it. Don't confuse these two things, and don't even think about using `mysql_query`. It's been deleted in PHP 7. My comments are full of links which I'd strongly recommend you spend some time reading. This code is extremely dangerous as it stands.

Comment: One further note: `mysql_error` is not the right function to use here. Although the `mysql_query` and `mysqli_query` interfaces differ in name by a single character, they are **completely different** internally. Please pay careful attention to the distinction here. Using the `mysqli` object-oriented interface will make this confusion less likely as `$stmt->execute()` cannot be confused with `mysql_query`.

Comment: then wat should i change

Comment: @sudharsan check my solution

Answer (score 1):

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into useraccount('Firstname','Lastname','Username','email','Password')values($Firstname,$Lastname,$Username,$email,$Password)");
```

and change button name

Answer (score 0):

If regardless to other errors, and if you just guess how to have your query run:
There are some reserved naming convention, and maybe your code could works in some situation, put column names between quotation marks.

```
INSERT into useraccount 
('Firstname','Lastname','Username','email','Password') 

VALUES 
    ($Firstname,$Lastname,$Username,$Password,$email);
```

I suggest you escape characters in variables you put into query.
This is a valuable article for you:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

But: Do not use this solution for production, as using login credential **while learning the code** is the worst possible way.

Answer (score 0):

change

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button><br>`

to

`<button type="submit" name="submit class="btn btn-default">Submit</button><br>`

because `$_POST['submit']` is not set since you forgot to set the name